# Ajax & Node JS : Paramaters values are NULL in backend

Tags: mysql, node.js, ajax, express, parameters

I'm working on a web app and I'm sending a post request with ajax to a node+express backend. The problem is that in the backend the values for all parameters are NULL, I have checked by `console.log(data)` on the front end before sending ajax request and I'm getting the values here but on the backend `request.query` has all params with NULL values.

**AJAX Request**

```js
const data = {
  first_name: fn,
  last_name: ln,
  email: email,
  password: password,
  job_title: job,
  security: security,
  mobile: mobile,
  remarks: remarks,
};

console.log("Data : ");
console.log(data);

$.post(
  "http://127.0.0.1:4000/user/add",
  data,
  function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  }
);
```

**Console Log For Data**

> Data :
> {first_name: 'a', last_name: 'a', email: 'admin@gmail.com', password: '13011301', job_title: 'CV-Specialist', …}

**Backend Code**

```js
app.post("/user/add", (req, res) => {
  const data = req.query;
  var sql =
    "Insert into users (first_name,last_name,email,password,job,security,mobile,remarks) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
  conn.query(
    sql,
    [
      data.first_name,
      data.last_name,
      data.email,
      data.password,
      data.job,
      data.security,
      data.mobile,
      data.remarks,
    ],
    function (err, result) {
      if (err) {
        res.send(err);
      } else {
        res.send("1 record inserted");
      }
    }
  );
});
```

**Backend Response**

> {code: 'ER_BAD_NULL_ERROR', errno: 1048, sqlMessage: "Column 'first_name' cannot be null", sqlState: '23000', index: 0, …}
> code
> :
> "ER_BAD_NULL_ERROR"
> errno
> :
> 1048
> index
> :
> 0
> sql
> :
> "Insert into users (first_name,last_name,email,password,job,security,mobile,remarks) values (NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)"
> sqlMessage
> :
> "Column 'first_name' cannot be null"

I have searched for solutions and explanations but I can't figure out what's causing this. Any help or hints will be appreciated, thank!

Answer (score 0):

The default content type header of jquery for Ajax is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. You are expected to send data in the query Params like so:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://www.example.com?' + $.param({first_name: 'a', last_name: 'a', email: 'admin@gmail.com', password: '13011301', job_title: 'CV-Specialist', …}),
  method: 'POST'
});
```

Either send all of your data encoded in query params as shown above

or

set headers to `application/json`

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'YourRestEndPoint',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type':'application/json'
    },
    method: 'POST',
    data: data,
    success: function(data){
      console.log('succes: '+data);
    }
  });
```

on the server side ensure you have body parser configured:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
.
.
.
.
.
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

In your middleware callback get data in `req.body` instead of `req.query` :

```
 app.post("/user/add", (req, res) => {
  const data = req.body;
  var sql =
    "Insert into users (first_name,last_name,email,password,job,security,mobile,remarks) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
  conn.query(
    sql,
    [
      data.first_name,
      data.last_name,
      data.email,
      data.password,
      data.job,
      data.security,
      data.mobile,
      data.remarks,
    ],
    function (err, result) {
      if (err) {
        res.send(err);
      } else {
        res.send("1 record inserted");
      }
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks! I tried both solutions, the first one didnt solve the problem infact i kept getting the same error. In the second solution trying req.body instead of req.query i get this error: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'first_name')`

Comment: Have you made changes both to the client and server side?

Comment: Yes, added the changes with body-parser to the server side as well.

Comment: If you are not getting data on the server side that means the client Side headers are not set or you are not sending the data In proper format using JSON.stringify()